# Symfony : Redirect errors 403, 500, ... to the 404 page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

I followed the instructions [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html) and I did a custom error.html.twig (The 3rd case). I did a custom controller too.

I have 2 problems:

**1st problem**
Where do I have to put my custom controller? I don't understand the doc for this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller

**2nd problem**
I'm trying to redirect 403, 500, ... errors to this page. Actually, when you try to access a folder you have "Access forbidden".

I tried to add this in the .htaccess : `ErrorDocument 403 http://www.xxx.fr/` but I don't know what the URL is of the 404 page.

## EDIT

Ok I understood where to put my controller but I get an error.

This is my **ExceptionController.php**

```php
namespace Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class ExceptionController
{
    public function showAction()
    {
        $dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/images/theme/404/';
        $dh  = opendir($dir);
        $errorFiles = array();
        while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
            if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..' && $filename[0] != '.')
                $errorFiles[] = $filename;

        shuffle($errorFiles);

        return $this->render('errors/show.html.twig', [
                    'gifs' => $errorFiles
        ]);
    }
}
```

**The error**

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1 UndefinedMethodException in ExceptionController.php line 30:
>   Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class
>   "Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController". in
>   ExceptionController.php line 30

This controller worked fine with a classic view.

Comment: 1) `ExceptionController.php` inside `AppBundle` "Controller" folder

Comment: From a quick glance at the Symfony page, I would say, you don't need any additional Apache directives.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche Actually I get "Oops, an error occured" if i try to access to an empty URL. But if I'm trying to access to a folder (I did Options -Indexes) I get "Access Forbidden". Then, it's not the same page ;)

Comment: @pavlovich It doesn't work. I put ExceptionController.php in my Controller folder but I get this error : Variable "gifs" does not exist in @Twig/Exception/error.html.twig at line 29

Comment: According to the Symfony page, the default exception controller looks for specific templates first. So I would guess there's an `error403.*` file somewhere, e.g. `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error403.html.twig`. If you don't want this, either remove or replace this file.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Look at the 3d case. I only have error.html.twig. I'm editing the question ;)

Comment: Yes, but have you removed all the other templates?

Comment: @OlafDietsche No. I only had this one. But I think I know how to redirect to this error page. I just have to write `ErrorDocument 403 http://www.xxx.fr/foo` because the foo route doesn't exist ;) But now the error page doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, then I have no more ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

- **1st problem** : You have to put it on a bundle and in your app/config/config.yml file :

  ```
  twig:
        exception_controller:  NameofMyBundleWhereIsTheControllerBundle:Exception:showException
  ```
- **2nd problem**: The best way as it's stated in the cookbook is to to create your own event listener which listens for the kernel.exception event and renders a page. By default, this exception is caught by the exception listening provided by Twig. You can do something like :

  ```
  <?php
  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

  public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
  {
      if ($event->getException() instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
         $response = $this->templating->renderResponse(/* sitemap */);

         $event->setResponse($response)
      }
  }
  ```

  (I haven't tested this code, so you should try it yourself! And you have       to inject the templating service into the event listener yourself, of course).
- **3rd problem or your edit**: In the doc they are 3 ways. You create a new controller but you have to copy past all the method that are defined in it. You extend ExceptionController and just change some method. Third possibility is to make a service for it (what I say in my 2nd problem).
  So in your case you try the second posibility and you so forget to extend from ExceptionController.

Comment: This is the default controller : http://pastebin.com/uAit4mSs there's no "extends" ;) That's why I don't understand. If I add it, I've another error : ClassNotFoundException in ExceptionController.php line 21:
Attempted to load class "Controller" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller"?

Comment: I edited my thirs answer. Hope it will be more clear. I edited to my code to. But don't forget it's a service and not a controller. For ref:http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand this answer in my case.